# PDFBox EOFException: null when setting textfield value

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to fill in a pdf form created with adobe acrobat, the form contains one text field named 'txt_name'. To fill in the form I am using Apache PDFBox.

Code to fill pdf form

```
        try {
            PDDocument pDDocument = 
            Loader.loadPDF(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:pdf/test.pdf"));
            PDAcroForm pDAcroForm = pDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
            pDAcroForm.getField("txt_name").setValue("test");
            pDDocument.save("./src/main/resources/pdf/generated/test.pdf");
            pDDocument.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

As you can see I am loading in the pdf file named 'test.pdf'. After this I want to fill in the field with the name 'txt_name' and set the value to 'test', however when I try to fill in the field I get an **EOFException**. I also get the error 'Could not load font file: C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\mstmc.ttf'. I do not have this file on my computer but when I try to find anything online about this I don't get any good results.

PDFBox version:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-RC1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I also tried different version but this would not work.

Stacktrace:

```
2021-05-19 10:46:22.549  WARN 29492 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.p.p.font.FileSystemFontProvider      : New fonts found, font cache will be re-built
2021-05-19 10:46:22.550  WARN 29492 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.p.p.font.FileSystemFontProvider      : Building on-disk font cache, this may take a while
2021-05-19 10:46:22.833 ERROR 29492 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.p.p.font.FileSystemFontProvider      : Could not load font file: C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\mstmc.ttf

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFDataStream.readUnsignedInt(TTFDataStream.java:150) ~[fontbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.readTableDirectory(TTFParser.java:298) ~[fontbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:139) ~[fontbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:87) ~[fontbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.addTrueTypeFont(FileSystemFontProvider.java:630) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.scanFonts(FileSystemFontProvider.java:374) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider.<init>(FileSystemFontProvider.java:350) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl$DefaultFontProvider.<clinit>(FontMapperImpl.java:135) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getProvider(FontMapperImpl.java:154) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFont(FontMapperImpl.java:418) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.findFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:381) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontMapperImpl.getFontBoxFont(FontMapperImpl.java:355) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<init>(PDType1Font.java:146) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.<clinit>(PDType1Font.java:63) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:75) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:143) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processSetFont(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:169) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processOperator(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:132) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processAppearanceStringOperators(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:109) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.<init>(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:87) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDVariableText.getDefaultAppearanceString(PDVariableText.java:93) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.<init>(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:115) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.constructAppearances(PDTextField.java:261) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTerminalField.applyChange(PDTerminalField.java:210) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.setValue(PDTextField.java:218) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1.jar:3.0.0-RC1]
    at welledmedia.backend.services.QuotationService.test(QuotationService.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at welledmedia.backend.controllers.QuotationController.test(QuotationController.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:204) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]

2021-05-19 10:46:23.001  WARN 29492 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.p.p.font.FileSystemFontProvider      : Finished building on-disk font cache, found 566 fonts
2021-05-19 10:46:23.188  WARN 29492 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument     : You are overwriting an existing file, this will produce a corrupted file if you're also reading from it
```

Comment: Please share the stack trace of your *EOFException*.

Comment: Look in the font directory again but open a CMD in admin mode. Move the file mstmc.ttf away or delete it. This is a mysterious file that seems to go around in China. I managed to get one and it's definitively not a font.

Comment: See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4524 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5095

Comment: @mkl Sorry I forgot to add it, JUst did it hope you can help me

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr whe looking in the fonts directory with cmd I am able to see the file, looking with file explorer I was not. You suggested it is a mysterious file but when looking at the date it was created (2019) I have had this file since I bought my computer meaning i did not download it from the internet, you sure I should delete it?

Comment: Apparently there is an issue in that file, so removing it should be ok (consider moving it to a different folder instead of deleting it if you want to play it save). But @Tilman probably `FileSystemFontProvider` should also be hardened to ignore files it cannot parse successfully.

Comment: @mkl Yes just found that out as well, I copied the file to my donwloads folder using cmd, after this I could see the file in my file explorer as well. When I tried to copy it back into my Fonts folder I was not able to because it was not a font. After delting the file it worked.

Comment: @mkl and Tilman Hausherr Thank you for the quick replies you were very helpful

Comment: The file explorer gives a "nice view" of the installed fonts, and doesn't show other files. @mkl IIRC the file is ignored. The OP is just scared by the error message.

Comment: @Tilman Well, yeah, it looks like it is caught. I thought it wasn't because the OP said he *got an EOFException*. But probably one shouldn't log this as ERROR but merely as warning to prevent users from being so scared. ;)

Comment: @mkl You're right, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the mstmc.ttf file worked for me, the file is not a font. PDFbox is trying to read this file but since it is not a font it is not able to read the file, this is what causes the error.

Thanks to @mkl and @Tilman hausherr who helped me out.